# Node red user based data in auth

Tags: node.js, node-red

Is it possible to add user based data when using custom login like this? I have custom auth module in use. Like this example:

```
 module.exports = {
   type: "credentials",
   authenticate: function(username,password) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve) {
           // Do whatever work is needed to validate the username/password
           // combination.
           if (valid) {
               // Resolve with the user object. Equivalent to having
               // called users(username);
               var user = { username: "admin", permissions: "*", customData: 'data' };
               resolve(user);
           } else {
               // Resolve with null to indicate the username/password pair
               // were not valid.
               resolve(null);
           }
       });
   },
}
```

I want to add token to user model. But looks like the user model removes other object parameters.

Comment: Where did you plan to use the token?

Comment: I plan to call rest api with the token.

Comment: Yes, but where in the authentication path? or do you mean in a flow?

Comment: I need to use external api. Our Node-Red is part of Loopback backend system. So querying Loopback api need user token.

Comment: You've still not answered the question, where in the Node-RED side are you trying to use the token

Comment: Ah, Sorry. I'm trying to use it in the flows, when editing custom flow.